# How to send the id of the input when clicking on an image which is in this particular input

Tags: javascript

I have 2 inputs and image in each input. When I
 click the image in the input I want to clear the text only in this input.
 How to to this?

Here is my function

```
function deleteText (id)
{
 //here i should get txtNameFirm ot txtNameOwner

var element = document.getElementsById(id);
element.value=" ";
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outer" >
    <input type="text" id = "txtNameOwner"  value="ENTER NAME OF OWNER"   /> 
    <img src="file:///C:/Users/gismo2/Dropbox/GISmoBusinessCatalogProject-Feb2013/IconResources/close_btn.png" onclick="deleteText('txtNameOwner')/>
</div>

<div class="outer" >
    <input type="text" id = "txtNameFirm"  value="ENTER NAME OF FIRM"   /> 
    <img src="file:///C:/Users/gismo2/Dropbox/GISmoBusinessCatalogProject-Feb2013/IconResources/close_btn.png" onclick="deleteText('txtNameFirm')" />
</div>
```

Comment: Keep the JavaScript error console open. It would have given an error message about the typoed method name.

Comment: check if my answer is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var element = document.getElementById(id);
element.value='';
```

You wrote `getElementsById` which is `getElementById`
Should work.